# Angular.js Showdown is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, markdown

I'm adding Showdown.js to my angular project and my directive is like:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('markdown', function() {
var converter = new Showdown.converter();
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var htmlText = converter.makeHtml(element.text());
        element.html(htmlText);
    }
}
```

});

It is still not processing markdown. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bradlygreen/8bENp/) is the fiddle and the example I'm using.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the console log revealed that Showdown wasn't being loaded, since you requesting directly from GitHub raw pages sent as text/plain, and jsfiddle requires proper mime types. Fixed in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8bENp/267/) to fetch Showdown from a CDN (along with Bootstrap for styles).

Also, it's usually good practice, for testing, to not reference global variables, like `Showdown` directly, but to inject `$window` and access it by `$window.Showdown`

```
function($window) {
   var converter = new $window.Showdown.converter();
   ...
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle is working but I can't make it work in my project with the same syntax. The only difference is my angular.js version is 1.2.6

Comment: Anything in the console in your project?

Comment: Okay I've sorted it out. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

If you open the console while in fiddle, you'll see pretty descriptive error message:

> Refused to execute script from
>   'https://raw.github.com/coreyti/showdown/master/compressed/showdown.js'
>   because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict
>   MIME type checking is enabled.

Workaround is to serve your library from rawgithub.com.

So, just remove the `.` from `raw.github` and your fiddle will work.

```
https://rawgithub.com/coreyti/showdown/master/compressed/showdown.js
```

<kbd>[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZYd5V/)</kbd>

Comment: but the same setup is not working in my project. Also your working fiddle is not working too :/